# Убрать текст из placeholder

Tags: html, css

Убрать текст из `placeholder` при клике вне `input`'a,- когда текст набран.

Как такового плейсхолдера здесь нет, так как необходимо было сделать красную звездочку. В данном случае здесь `span` с `position:absolute`.

```css
.header-call__label {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-call__input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 1.333rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-call__input:hover, .header-call__input:active, .header-call__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #848484;
}

.header-call__input-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header-call__input-text span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="header-call__label">
  <input class="header-call__input" id="headName" type="text"/>
  <div class="header-call__input-text">
     Имя фамилия<span>*</span></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Не меняет цвет, потому что песочница не умеет в препроцессоры.

Comment: Странно... но я не вижу в вашем коде "placeholder". И что значит "когда текст набран" ? когда набирается тест в инпуте, placeholder по любому пропадает

Comment: https://codepen.io/wernstrom/pen/woGjKv
https://codepen.io/sivan/pen/alKwf
https://codepen.io/pablopo/pen/KrBmad
....

Comment: @Denisoed хорошее замечание, подкорректировал вопрос

Answer (score 1):

На `css` с использованием атрибута `placeholder-shown`.

Минусы:
 1. нет поддержки `ie`, `edge`;
 2. обязательно задание `placeholder` через атрибут (в примере состоит из одного пробела).

```css
.header-call__label {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-call__input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 1.333rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-call__input:hover, .header-call__input:active, .header-call__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #848484;
}

.header-call__input-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header-call__input-text span {
  color: red;
}
.header-call__input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .header-call__input-text{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label class="header-call__label">
  <input class="header-call__input" id="headName" type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <span class="header-call__input-text">Имя фамилия<span>*</span></span>
</label>
```

С использованием `javascript`

```js
function placeholder(){
  if(this.value == ''){
    $(this).siblings('.header-call__input-text').show();
  }else{
    $(this).siblings('.header-call__input-text').hide();
  }
}
$('.header-call__input').each(placeholder);
$('.header-call__input').on('input', placeholder);
```

```css
.header-call__label {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-call__input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 1.333rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-call__input:hover, .header-call__input:active, .header-call__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #848484;
}

.header-call__input-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header-call__input-text span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="header-call__label">
  <input class="header-call__input" id="headName" type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <span class="header-call__input-text">Имя фамилия<span>*</span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: у 2го способа лучше поддержка браузеров?

Comment: Да, у второго способа  лучшая поддержка браузерами.